# What account should be debited using double entry accounting for a stock spinoff transaction

Tags: stocks, double-entry, bookkeeping, ledger-cli

I use [ledger](https://www.ledger-cli.org/) for tracking my personal finances.  I'm trying to record a transaction where a stock I owned spun off shares of another company.  (The specific case I'm referring to is when [BioTime spun off AgeX Therapetics](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20181128005221/en/BioTime-Announces-Distribution-AgeX-Therapeutics-Shares).)

I owned shares of BTX and received shares of AGE.  Should this be recorded like a dividend where an asset is credited with the shares and an income account is debited?  Should there be a specific account used to indicate that the AGE shares were spun off from BTX?

Comment: Could you show us how you recorded the initial purchase of BTX?